# Scale an image every time it collide with another

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, animation, uiimageview

here is my code :

```
-(void)collision{
    if(CGRectIntersectsRect(imageView.frame,centre.frame)){
        imageView.alpha=0;
        [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
        [UIView setAnimationDuration:1.0f];
        centre.transform=CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1.3, 1.3);
        [UIView commitAnimations];
    }
}
```

When imageView collide with centre centre become bigger.
my problem is that when "imageView" collide with "centre" a second time the animation doesn't work. I want to make centre bigger and bigger and bigger every time imageView collide with center, but it become bigger just one time . Sorry for my english I'm french :/ How can I solve this please ?

Comment: What language is this? What are you coding for? An iPhone or android? Try replacing your `scale` tag with a tag related to your programming language

Answer (score 2):

The reason your view is not scaled second time is that you apply the same transform to it every time - you need to change applied transformation every time:

```
...
centre.transform = CGAffineTransformScale(centre.transform, 1.3, 1.3);
...
```

Comment: when I use your code my image "centre" become big ver quiqly and all my screen become in one second my image.

Comment: @jean, yes probably because your scale factor is too large + it grows exponentially (i.e. it is multiplied on 1.3 every time). You may want to use lower scale factor and/or use peaches's approach with tracking scale value separately and add 0.3 to it on each iteration

Comment: I think that you are right it grows exponentially, so how could I solve this because I don't really understand "se peaches's approach with tracking scale value separately and add 0.3 to it on each iteration" :/

Comment: create scale instance variable in your class, init it with 1.0 at start and add 0.3 to it each time in your function. then create your transform as peaches suggested

Comment: You can also create static local variable inside your method but in that case you won't be able to access it outside of the method so creating ivar is better I think

Comment: sorry but I'm new to xcode and it's very hard for me to understand without code so if it's possible can you post a code :/

Answer (score 2):

It may be that the scale is not applied after. Try incrementing the scale value each time. Declare a `float` to keep track of the object's scale. Then, during each collision, before you execute the `CGAffineTransformMakeScale(scale, scale)` do this:

```
scale = scale + 0.3;
```

#### Example

```
-(void)collision{
    if(CGRectIntersectsRect(imageView.frame,centre.frame)){
        scale = scale + 0.3;
        imageView.alpha=0;
        [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
        [UIView setAnimationDuration:1.0f];
        centre.transform=CGAffineTransformMakeScale(scale, scale);
        [UIView commitAnimations];
    }
...
```

Comment: can you give me a sample code because I don't really understand :/

Comment: +1, only he'll need to use float, not integer, to store scale value :)

Comment: I just revised my suggestion to say "Declare a `float`..."

Comment: there is a big problem with your code: first when there is a collision for the first time the scale is reduced and then when there is a second collision the image become very big and disapear

Comment: you need to initialize the field scale to 1. `float scale = 1;` Or something along those lines. What language is this coded in?

Comment: Show me the line where you declare the variable `scale`

Comment: I declare it on my ".h " and I write float scale;

Comment: I;m not sure if you can initalize a variable in a header file. try `float scale = 1.0;`

Comment: then you need to set that variable somewhere else. Nd if the scale changes too quickly, then change the `0.3` to something smaller, like `0.1` or `0.15`